# Different durations for different properties using WebKit transitions/animation

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit, webkit-transition

I'm using WebKit transition to animate certain CSS changes.
For example, say I've got a red box that I want to change to green when someone hovers. I use this:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
-webkit-transition-property: background;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
```

That works great. But now, say I want it to also slide downwards a bit. I use this:

```
-webkit-transition-property: background, margin;
```

That also works okay, but I want the box to slide down quickly (say 50ms). I can't change `-duration` because that would make the color animate fast.

**How can I assign different durations to different properties in CSS animations?**
I'm fine with using keyframe animations if necessary, but I haven't seen a way that they can help me.

**[jsfiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ8d7/)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duratons can be comma-separated, corresponding to the transitioned properties, ie:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 50ms, 200ms;
-webkit-transition-property: margin, background;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bQ8d7/1/